# Encoding issues while sending RSA encrypted data in python

Tags: python, encryption, encoding, rsa, python-requests

I'm using rsa and requests libraries to send rsa-encrypted data through HTTP. Here's example of my code for this task:

```
import rsa
import requests
import json

rsa_pub, rsa_priv = rsa.newkeys(512)
data = {}

phone = b'{}'.format(123456789)
encrypted = rsa.encrypt(phone, rsa_pub)
data['phone'] = encrypted

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
res = requests.post('http://example.com', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, timeout=15)
```

But i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 13, in <module>
    res = requests.post('http://example.com', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, timeout=15)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Is there any way to convert rsa-data to utf-8? This seems to be the problem of making json data for request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest would be to encode the ciphertext as Base 64. I hope, you're not using this code for anything meaningful. RSA keys should be at least 2048 bit long. If you want to encrypt arbitrary data, then you should use hybrid encryption approach.